# How can we reload header view inside our collection view

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I've been looking for a way to reload my collection view header. So I have a collection view header & a CollectionViewCell that only contains an image. Now when the cell is press, I would like to display the image in the header view without calling collectionView.reloadData(). This is how my didSelectItemAt & didDeselectItemAt method looks like.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedImage = images[indexPath.item]
    let imageCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CollectionCell
    imageCell.photoBackgroundView.backgroundColor = .red

    collectionView.reloadData()
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let imageCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! ImagePickerCell
    imageCell.photoBackgroundView.backgroundColor = .black
}
```

So when I select a cell the view turns red, when I deselect it the view turns black. This [video here](https://youtu.be/DJzskcAzi7E), shows how the behavior without reloading the collectionView. Now here is were I would like to reload the header view.

If I do use collectionView.reloadData(), this is the [outcome.](https://youtu.be/lHkeO3rpGtw) How would I be able to reload the header or the collectionView where the header view displays the selected cell image & turns red.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like global instance for that. Like

```
class YourClass: UIViewController {

 /// Profile imageView
    var profileImageview = UIImageView()

}
```

In CollectionView cellforItem assign a imageview. Like

```
let imageCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CollectionCell
profileImageview = imageCell.imageView
```

Then when every you selecting collectionViewCell

You can call a function to change a image of imageView. Like

```
func updateImage() {
  profileImageview.image = UIImage()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm trying to understand why sometimes you cast the cell in CollectionCell and sometimes in ImagePickerCell, anyway try to change your functions in these

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CollectionCell
    cell?.photoBackgroundView.backgroundColor = .red
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CollectionCell
    cell?.photoBackgroundView.backgroundColor = .black
}
```